# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sqlalchemy' -- Conda package manager

Tags: python, flask, pip, flask-sqlalchemy, conda

I am quite new to flask and still a beginner in python and I am running into package issues with **sqlalchemy**. I have created a virtual environment with `conda` called `flask_app_env` and it is active as I show in the terminal output and then executed the below commands in terminal. I have used pip package manager to install sqlalchemy among the other flask packages.

Python version- 3.7.4 but when I try to execute the command `from sqlalchemy import create_engine` in terminal it throws the error: **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sqlalchemy'**

Any direction would be much appreciated.

[image: lask]

Comment: If you use the same version of SQLAlchemy in your root and our virtual environment, do you get any improvements? But I am only guessing....

Comment: @AndiSchroff I have gotten this error to go away by removing the packages and reinstalling them with `python -m pip install <package-name>` I know the *-m* is a module flag but im unclear what it is doing. I have *brew* and *conda* setup as my package managers but im very unclear how pip is working with them. My current version of python is set as 3.7.4.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. When running the script from crontask I was getting the same error. However, after running the task from terminal, I got additinaly error on missing 'psycopg2' module, which is a database driver for postgres used by SQLAlchemy.
Simply: `conda install psycopg2` solved the problem.